# Jooq compare timestamps by day/month/year

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, timestamp, jooq

I am trying to perform a comparison between timestamps using jooq. I need to find out if the 2 timestamps are on the same day/month/year.

To do this in jpql I was using the `day()`/`month()`/`year()`/`hour()` methods.

I tried using the `Field.compare(Comparator, Field)` method, however this doesnt use the standard java comparator but instead uses an enum from Jooq.

an example of this in jpql is

```sql
SELECT s from Service s WHERE day(s.serviceDate) = day(s.createdAt) and 
month(s.serviceDate) = month(s.createdAt)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Using `day()` and `month()` functions

[Your own solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52722772/521799) is absolutely correct, of course but do note there are convenience methods [`DSL.day()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#day-org.jooq.Field-) and [`DSL.month()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#month-org.jooq.Field-) that you could use as well:

```java
ctx.select()
   .from(SERVICE)
   .where(day(SERVICE.SERVICE_DATE).eq(day(SERVICE.CREATED_AT)))
   .and(month(SERVICE.SERVICE_DATE).eq(month(SERVICE.CREATED_AT)))
   .fetch();
```

#### Your actual question

However, your actual question was a different one:

> I need to find out if the 2 timestamps are on the same day/month/year.

You should probably include the year as well. Otherwise, two timestamps on the same date in different years would match, e.g. `2017-01-01` and `2018-01-01`. Here's an alternative using [`DSL.trunc()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#trunc-org.jooq.Field-):

```
ctx.select()
   .from(SERVICE)
   .where(trunc(SERVICE.SERVICE_DATE).eq(trunc(SERVICE.CREATED_AT)))
   .fetch();
```

As always, the above is assuming you're using the following static import

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

Comment: Thanks this gives me 2 different methods with JOOQ that I can definitely see myself using. Unfortunately the `DSL.trunc()` method will not work in my case as we have to deal with timezones so my `hour()` logic is required, didn't realize that would be important for the question but glad you supplied both options

Answer (score 1):

The way to perform this is using the [extract](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#extract-java.util.Date-org.jooq.DatePart-) method and supplying a DatePart enum.

For example

```
Condition dayCondition = SERVICE.SERVICE_DATE.extract(DatePart.DAY)
  .eq(SERVICE.CREATED_AT.extract(DatePart.DAY);

Condition monthCondition = SERVICE.SERVICE_DATE.extract(DatePart.MONTH)
  .eq(SERVICE.CREATED_AT.extract(DatePart.MONTH);


dslContext.select()
    .from(SERVICE)
    .where(dayCondtion.and(monthCondition)).fetch();
```